# An error occurred in the db.QueryRow step

Tags: go

When I sign up, an error occurs at db.QueryRow and returns

> Error 1 The server cannot create your account.

```
func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if r.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "signup.html")
        return
    }

    username := r.FormValue("username")
    password := r.FormValue("password")
    var user string
    err := db.QueryRow("select username from members where username=?", username).Scan(&user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "1 Server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
        return
    }

    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "2 server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
            return
        }
        _, err = db.Exec("insert into members(username, password) values(?,?", username, hashedPassword)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "3 server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
            return
        }
        w.Write([]byte("User created!"))
        return
    case err != nil:
        http.Error(w, "4 server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
        return
    default:
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)

    }
}
```

Comment: You should log the value of `err` for debugging. Also show your imports and how you initialize `db`. For a new account, `err` is likely to be `sql.ErrNoRows` but you never reach that case since you error out right away.

Comment: I using fmt.Println(err).
result >> sql: no rows in result set

Comment: So you receive a `sql.ErrNoRows` and return right away. All the code you have under `case err == sql.ErrNoRows` is never reached.

Comment: How can I edit the code on 'signup'? I don't know what to do.

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to learn the language.